# Can AAD Tenant (B2C) be moved from one region to another?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

If I have created an Azure AAD tenant (B2C) in one region (East US), can I move it to some other region (West Europe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Country/Region will be selected at the time of tenant Creation, It can't be changed.

Depending on the country you choose, Azure AD B2C selects the closest data center/region that will hold your Azure AD B2C directory. Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/data-residency#data-residency) for Data residence details.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can Microsoft Support do it for us?

Comment: Yeah, you can rasie a [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/support-options) they may help you in one or another way